# getting first row of table by criteria query

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

How can I get the first row of a table by using `criteria` or `HQL` query?

Table creation script

```
   CREATE TABLE MonthlySubscriber(MSISDN bigint(20) 
   NOT NULL, MonthOfYear int(11) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (MSISDN));
```

Comment: Accept the answer and help people to trust on provided solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes you can do that with `setMaxResults` & `setFirstResult` in criteria

**Sample Code**

```
Criteria queryCriteria = session.createCriteria(MonthlySubscriber.class);
queryCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
queryCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
monthlySubscriberList = queryCriteria .list();
```

Comment: Why the .setFirstResult(0) ?

Comment: @MarkW setFirstResult is used for setting starting point from where take the result from the list. In this case, we need the result from first element of the list.

Answer (score 4):

you could do that like this:

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        String sql= "select b.wcd, a.optime from UseWaterRecord a, WellBasicInfo b where a.stcd=:a_stcd and b.stcd=:b_stcd ORDER BY a.optime desc";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
        query.setString("a_stcd", "10100405");
        query.setString("b_stcd", "10100405");
        query.setFirstResult(0);
        query.setMaxResults(1);

        List wrwmList = query.list();
```

Comment: this is not via criteria query

Comment: BUT, it's HQL query

Answer (score 1):

```
 Criteria queryCriteria = currentSession.createCriteria(Project.class);
 queryCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
 queryCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
 entity = (Project) queryCriteria.uniqueResult(); // Casting to the Entity class
```

Comment: uniqueResult(), nice.

Answer (score -3):

```
public Criteria setFirstResult(int firstResult)
```

This method takes an integer that represents the first row in your result set, starting with row 0. [REFER](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm)

Comment: `setFirstResult` use to get start row but it gives all rows from below that. for that must have to use `setMaxResults`.

Comment: @JubinPatel isn't `setFirstResult` explicit in conjunction with `setMaxResults`?