# How to Fetch Single record using Criteria in java

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, nhibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

```
Table User{    
 String id;
 String name;
 Date created_at;
 Set<Subscription> key;
}

Table Subscription  {
  String key;
  Date expiry;
}
```

I have to find user using list of subscription key but since one key is having multiple user. I have to take only the first user which is created first.

My code :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
                            CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
                            Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
                            SetJoin<User, Subscription> subscriptionJoin= userRoot.join(USer_.key);
                            
                            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(subscriptionJoin.get(.key).in(keys)));
                            criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(userRoot_.get(user_.CREATED_AT)));
```

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825610/getting-first-row-of-table-by-criteria-query

Comment: I am passing list of subscription key, if I will use 
queryCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
queryCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
then I will get only 1 record every time.

Comment: I want to fetch only one user per subscription key as there can be multiple user for a single key.

And I am passing key(1234, 2213). currently DB is returning 3 records because in DB there are two user having same key. But my expectation is I should get 2 record only.

Comment: there is another thread with probably same requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914988/use-hibernate-criteria-api-to-return-first-row-of-each-group you need to add ``group by`` subscription id